# Wild cards search in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, unix

The project in our company includes a variety of files. Many a times, it becomes necessary to search all but a few file types. Is there a way to exclude some extensions while doing a searching `*.*` file search.

One way I know of is to do it via resource filters, but then those exclusions become permanent. What I want is to search for `*.*`, while removing say `*.jsp` or `*.sql` or `*.cpp` files on the fly.

Thanks,
Ron

Comment: if you mean to use the unix shell toolkit, you'll get more eyes on your problem by adding a tag for bash or ksh, or ?? Otherwise, a tag for the programming language that is driving your project will help people decide if they can help on your question or not. Good luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not mention *how* you are performing the searches. Personally, I am quite comfortable with the Unix command line, so I have found that having a couple of terminals open on the directory of my Eclipse workspace always comes handy.

On the shell command line, using [`find`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [`sort`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) to show all files under the current directory:

```
$ find -type f | sort
./a/a0.txt
./a/a1.doc
./b/b0.rtf
./b/b1.cpp
./b/b2.jsp
./c/c0.jsp
./c/c1.sql
./c/c2.cpp
```

To show all files except for those matching `*.cpp`:

```
$ find -type f ! -name '*.cpp' | sort
./a/a0.txt
./a/a1.doc
./b/b0.rtf
./b/b2.jsp
./c/c0.jsp
./c/c1.sql
```

To show all files except for those matching `*.cpp` or `*.jsp`:

```
$ find -type f ! -name '*.cpp' ! -name '*.jsp' | sort
./a/a0.txt
./a/a1.doc
./b/b0.rtf
./c/c1.sql
```

To show all files matching `?1.*` except for those matching `*.sql`:

```
$ find -type f -name '?1.*' ! -name '*.sql' | sort
./a/a1.doc
./b/b1.cpp
```

`find` is the standard Unix command line utility for file searching. Unfortunately, while some of its options are standardized, others are different among the various Unix-like operating systems. You should probably have a look at its manual page (`man find`) to find out the options that your version of `find` accepts. The manual page I linked to is for [GNU find](http://www.gnu.org/s/findutils/), which is what most (all?) Linux distributions come with.

If you use Eclipse itself to perform the searches, you can do the following:

1. Click on `Search` in the menu bar
2. Select `File`
3. A `File Search` dialog will pop-up
4. Click on the `Choose` button next to the `File name patterns` textbox
5. Click on `Select all` - then remove the check-mark from those extensions you wish to exclude, making sure to exclude `*.*` as well
6. A pattern list will appear in the `File name patterns` textbox
7. Click `Search` and a new view with the search results will appear

Disclaimer: this is on Eclipse 3.7.1

This method does not seem to be as powerful as using `find`, but it offers better integration with Eclipse.